# Angular Input property in Bootstrap modal is undefined

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap 4 modal inside an Angular 4 app. I'm not sure if having a component inside another component is influencing the behavior somehow, but I can't find a reason why an @Input parameter inside the modal component is always undefined. I want a table where the rows are clickable, and clicking on each one should open the details on a modal. Here is what I have:

### Parent Component Template

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Appraisal</th>
      <th>Last Modification</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let appraisal of appraisals" (click)="appraisalDetail(appraisal)">
      <td>
        <span>{{appraisal.name}}</span>
        <app-appraisal-modal *ngIf="appraisal" [selectedAppraisal]="appraisal"></app-appraisal-modal>
      </td>
      <td>{{appraisal.lastModifiedStr}}</td>
      <td class="{{appraisal.status === 'Pending' ? 'pending' : '' }}">{{appraisal.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Parent Component Code

```
appraisalDetail(appraisal: Appraisal): void {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AppraisalModalComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.selectedAppraisal = appraisal;
}
```

### Child Template

```
<div *ngIf="selectedAppraisal">
 <div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{selectedAppraisal.name}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" 
        (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <span>{{selectedAppraisal.name}} detail goes here.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### AppModule

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
LoginComponent,
EmployeeComponent,
AppraisalComponent,
FeedbackReferenceComponent,
AppraisalModalComponent
  ],
   imports: [
AppRoutingModule,
HttpModule,
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
NgbModule.forRoot(),
BrowserModule,
FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppraisalModalComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

To make it weirder, I can print the selected value on console just fine, but on debug time it comes as undefined, and the screen just goes grey (as if the modal was opened fine) but no modal is shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your code, and I think I found the culprit! Seems that bootstrap's css for class `modal fade` is causing this. So by removing it, your modal should display fine hopefully!

```html
<div *ngIf="selectedAppraisal">
<!--<div class="modal fade"> -->   <----- HERE!
<div>   <--- replaced with
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{selectedAppraisal.name}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" 
        (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <span>{{selectedAppraisal.name}} detail goes here.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I think your code should work just fine without having the child tag in the parent template... i.e, the following shouldn't be needed! (Check Plunker)

```html
<app-appraisal-modal *ngIf="appraisal" [selectedAppraisal]="appraisal"></app-appraisal-modal>
```

Here is a **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XLLw3xuQpllDJ0P5J6MZ?p=preview)** to play with.

Comment: You're completely right, the child tag wasn't needed as well. Thanks a lot :)